# DockerFile: on container stop. Run commands on stop signal

Tags: docker, dockerfile, forever

I have a process that runs in the background of my docker contained website. I am currently using forever npm package to keep this running.

I would like to clean up the process cleanly when the container is stopped/killed.

I know that all process started in the container should be auto killed after 10 seconds of waiting, but I'd rather tell forever to stop the process on this signal....

How do I write these cleanup scripts in my docker file to execute when a docker container is getting closed or killed?

Answer (score 0):

In your script (entry-point, command) you should run command with `exec command_name "$@"` and your application has to handle the signals.

Comment: can you explain what `exec command_name "$@"` means? the dollar sign and at sign are black magic to me

Comment: `exec` run yours command and allow send signals sent to docker container to your running command. If you run docker in foreground and you press Ctrl+c, `SIGTERM` will be send to container and thanks to `exec` your running command will know about that. Now you have to handle that signal.
For `$@` go and read https://devhints.io/bash#arguments

Comment: Thank you @d0iek